# What's the error in this php script?

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I wrote a php script that will send the information entered in my html form, to my email.
When testing the script using 000webhost.com, it says that there is a parse error on the 8th line.
I tried to figure it out but I can't.
Can anyone please help me to find the error I made when writing the php script?

**This is the php script**

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" Name: $name \n Email: $email \n Message: $message;
$recipient = "angrybullet2@gmail.com";
$subject = "New message";
$mailheader = "From: angrybullet2-contact-us \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "<div align=center><font face=calibri color=#009933<h3>Thank You! Your message is being proceeded.</h3></font><br><hr><a href=contact.htm>Go back to the contact us page</a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspOR&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<a href=home.htm>Go to the home page</a></div>"
?>
```

**Any help or advice will be surely appreciated. Thanks in advance!**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a "spot-the typo" question.

Comment: I'm not going to post an answer, just check all your ending semi-colons, some are missing.

Comment: @MattBall You sir, are SPOT-ON ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You forgot a closing quote:

```
$formcontent=" Name: $name \n Email: $email \n Message: $message;
----------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Try:

```
$formcontent=" Name: $name \n Email: $email \n Message: $message";
```

Or:

```
$formcontent=" Name: " . $name . " \n Email: " . $email . " \n Message: " . $message;
```

On top of that, your last echo statement has multiple errors (including missing quotes) and a missing semicolon at the end.

Comment: But my echo statement is working well on another php script

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a closing quote here

> $formcontent=" Name: $name \n Email: $email \n Message: $message;

It should be

> $formcontent= "Name: $name \n Email: $email \n Message: $message";

Comment: Why the -1? How is my answer wrong?